# why can't parent components get the data from child component? 1

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading

[this picture consedred for child module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16On4.png)

[this picture for parent module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1HHU.png)

[this picture for routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b2lo.png)

the issue appear  when i moving to child component 
[issue in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omb8m.png)

Comment: post code here  instead of image.

Comment: @slimabdi. Pls post code

Comment: It still baffles me that people post images of code... Surely it's a lot easier to copy and paste the code (ill-formatted too, just with no indents or whatever), than it is to screen cap, upload, and link to...

Comment: Can you please post component **template** HTML markups too? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the CommonModule to every child module for *ngIf to work. I think importing it to your appModule will work for every child module but I am not entirely sure. Try to import it in the particular module and see if it works.

About your topic title, Angular child modules inherit from their parents but parents do not get anything from the childen, and that is the whole point of lazy loading components, to load a component or module only when it is needed.

Hope it helps